# depgraph-maven-plugin throws com.github.ferstl.depgraph.dependency.NodeResolution.OMİTTED_FOR_DUPLİCATE

Tags: spring-boot, maven, degraph

I have a problem to draw a graph through depgraph-maven-plugin.

I have a maven project for Spring Boot app named food ordering system and its main package is defined as `com.food.ordering.system`

After I run this command shown below

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:aggregate -DcreateImage=true -DreduceEdges=false -Dscope=compile "-Dincludes=com.food.ordering.system*:*"
```

I got this error message shown below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:4.0.2:aggregate (default-cli) on project food-ordering-system: Execution default-cli of goal com.github.ferstl:de
pgraph-maven-plugin:4.0.2:aggregate failed: Unable to read style configuration classpath:default-style.json.
[ERROR] Location: line 35, column 5
[ERROR] Details: Cannot deserialize Map key of type `com.github.ferstl.depgraph.dependency.NodeResolution` from String "omitted-for-duplicate": not a valid representation: No enum cons
tant com.github.ferstl.depgraph.dependency.NodeResolution.OMİTTED_FOR_DUPLİCATE
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

How can I fix it?